# Angular / Jest / Firebase Test fail on AppComponent - NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options

Tags: angular, jestjs, nrwl-nx

`Angular v13.0.0`  `@angular/fire 7.2.0` `jest 27.2.3`

This is an app generated by Nrwl NX. I have added Firebase via `@angular/fire`

spec to produce error

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {


    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule,
            ],
            declarations: [AppComponent],
        }).compileComponents();
    });

    it('should create the app', () => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        const app = fixture.componentInstance;
        expect(app).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

When I run `nx test` the app fails with

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[GuiSecurityAuthService -> AngularFireAuth -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]: 
      NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!
```

If I add the `AngularFireModule` to the spec as follows now a new error

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {


    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule,
                AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
            ],
            declarations: [AppComponent],
        }).compileComponents();
    });

    it('should create the app', () => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        const app = fixture.componentInstance;
        expect(app).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

New error `INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition`

Suggestions to fix are to add the following to the file.  The problem is this is not a server app.  It is a browser app.

```
/**
 * @jest-environment node
 */
```

Produces error `ReferenceError: window is not defined`

Not sure what to do to get a passing test.

Comment: What APIs of the angufire are you using? You need to mock away the ones youre using.

Comment: I need to learn more about testing, what does Mock away mean?

Comment: Update, I created a karma based version and it works with the `AngularFireModule.initializeApp`.  Jest seems to be part of the problem